# Why I am not read xml file using FileSystemResource class

Tags: java, spring

Problem:

I have created a program that will read my applicationContext.xml file from the specified path using FilesystemResource and call B.Method.
I am unable to understood why I am getting error like this:

> Can anyone guide me how to solve this problem:

Below is the Code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Resource res=null;
    BeanFactory factory=null;
    Object obj=null;
    WishMessageGenerator generator=null;
    //Locate Cfg File
    res=new FileSystemResource("com/jc/cfgs/applicationContext.xml");
    //Create IOC Container      
    factory=new XmlBeanFactory(res);
    //getBean Class Object      
    obj=factory.getBean("wish");
    //TypeCasting       
    generator=(WishMessageGenerator)obj;
    //Invoke Businees Method        
    System.out.println("Message ="+generator.wishMsg("jalaj"));

}

}
```

Error Shown :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from file [/Users/mansi/Desktop/springapp/SpringApp4/com/jc/cfgs/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: com/jc/cfgs/applicationContext.xml (No such file or directory)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:344)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanFactory.<init>(XmlBeanFactory.java:79)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanFactory.<init>(XmlBeanFactory.java:67)
at com.jc.test.Test.main(Test.java:20)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: com/jc/cfgs/applicationContext.xml (No such file or directory)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
at org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource.getInputStream(FileSystemResource.java:115)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:330)
... 4 more
```

[DirectoryStructure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x5ZB3.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the resource is in the classpath, you should not use `FileSystemResource` that is designed to specify a absolute path.

`ClassPathResource` that is also  a `org.springframework.core.io.Resource` implementation is more suitable.

In your actual code, the `src` folder is in the classpath, so this should be fine :

```
res = new ClassPathResource("com/jc/cfgs/applicationContext.xml");
```

Comment: If I delete applicationContext.xml from the classPath.Then?See the above DirectoryStructure.I have done editing

Comment: Why do you want to delete it ? You should externalize information that changes according to the running environments, not all the spring configuration.

Comment: I don't want to keep in classPath.I want to keep in a specified path

Comment: You should not and if you want to do it, the file should not be in your project source code but outside and you should provide a absolute path for FileSystemResource